# How to use $docBoost in solr while doing boosting at index time?

Tags: mysql, apache, jdbc, solr, dih

I was searching about the usage of $docBoost in solr to boost a particular set of documents but was unable to find any examples or documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example at following [url](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Index-time-boosting-with-DIH-td3206271.html)

Here is an example

```
<dataConfig>
<script><![CDATA[
function f1(row) {
// Add boost
row.put('$docBoost',1.5);
return row;
}
]]></script>
<document>
<entity name="e" pk="id" transformer="script:f1"
query="select * from X">
....
</entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```